# Unable to add style class or access elements' attributes from jquery each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a table, which looks like this:

```
<table id="ctoTable" class="table table-bordered">
<thead> ... </thead>
<tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#1" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#2" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#3" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#4" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#5" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#6" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#7" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#8" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#9" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#76" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr id="kpi#77" class="js-editable"></tr>
    <tr></tr>
</tbody>
```

and I would like to be make some kind of filter which allows me to show and hide some of the rows. I was pretty sure that I could do it on this way but unfortunately it does not work. Not only that I am not able to add/remove classes, I can't event get an attribute of an th.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#hideRows" ).click(function() {
        var rows = $('.js-editable');
        $.each(rows, function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
            //item.addClass("hideElement"); //try to add the class to the tr
            console.log(item.attr("id")); //try to print tr id in console
        });
    });
});
```

as a result only the first row will be printed out

```
<tr id="kpi#1" class="js-editable"></tr>
```

and than the method breaks without any errors logged.
Could someone expain to me what is happening here and how could I fix this issue.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "the method breaks without any errors logged." How does it *break*? Can you provide a JSFiddle or JSBin example so others can verify that "no errors are logged". Typically error swallowing is found in promises or bad try/catch blocks not in the examples you provided.

Comment: Don't make IDs with octothorpes in them, it is silly and I think wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `item` inside the loop is a dom element reference not a jQuery object so you can't access jQuery methods directly from `item`.

Instead you need to get a jQuery object reference for `item` by passing it to jQuery like `$(item)` and then you can use jQuery methods like

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#hideRows").click(function () {
        var rows = $('.js-editable');
        rows.each(function (index, item) {
            console.log(item);
            //$(item).addClass("hideElement"); //try to add the class to the tr
            console.log($(item).attr("id")); //try to print tr id in console
        });
    });
});
```

But if you just want to add a class there is no need to use a loop

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $("#hideRows").click(function () {
        var rows = $('.js-editable');
        rows.addClass("hideElement");
    });
});
```

Also note then it is better to use [.each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/) instead of [$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) to iterate over jQuery object.

Comment: The difference between `$.each()` and `.each()` is not the significant solution. What is the significant bit of knowledge is the `$(item)`. Perhaps your synopsis should reference that first and leave the `$.each()` vs. `.each()` as an aside in the *no needs for a loop* section.

Comment: ... and I'll need the loop becaus the row shoul be hidden only in a specific case which will be tested inside the loop.

Comment: @amsalk you might find [`.filter(function)`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to be more suitable for this then `.each()`: http://jsbin.com/remewe/1/edit?js,output

Answer (score 1):

If you write `item.attr`, it will return an error, because, by this way `item` is not a jQuery object.

Change it like this:

```
$(item).attr("id")
```

Comment: Before I posted this anwser, I did a test here: http://jsfiddle.net/vdzf3xn8/ and view the console: `Uncaught TypeError: item.attr is not a function` ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

`console.log($(item).attr("id"))`  instead of `console.log(item.attr("id"))`

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#hideRows" ).click(function() {
        var rows = $('.js-editable');
        $.each(rows, function(index, item) {
            console.log(item);
            //item.addClass("hideElement"); //try to add the class to the tr
            console.log($(item).attr("id")); //try to print tr id in console
        });
    });
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5gtrjkcL/)

Comment: Or just `console.log(item.id)`